# Merge Two Streams

Tags: java, merge, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to implement a method to merge the values in two `Stream`s based on a `Comparator` for the values.

I had a way to do this, where I iterate over the streams and insert the values into a `Stream.Builder`, but I have not been able to figure out how to make a lazy-evaluated version (the way many stream operations are), so it can deal with infinite streams as well.

All I want it to do is perform a *single* merging pass on the input data, *not* sort the streams (in fact, it is likely that the streams will be disordered; this disorder needs to be preserved).

```
static Stream<E> merge(Stream<E> first, Stream<E> second, Comparator<E> c)
```

How can I lazily merge two streams like this?

If I were doing this with two `Queue`s as input and some `Consumer` as output, it would be fairly simple:

```
void merge(Queue<E> first, Queue<E> second, Consumer<E> out, Comparator<E> c){
    while(!first.isEmpty() && !second.isEmpty()
        if(c.compare(first.peek(), second.peek()) <= 0)
            out.accept(first.remove());
        else
            out.accept(second.remove());
    for(E e:first)
        out.accept(e);
    for(E e:second)
        out.accept(e);
}
```

But I need to do this with lazy evaluation, and streams.

To address the comments, here are some example inputs and the result:

Example 1:

```
merge(
    Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
    Stream.of(2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2),
    Comparator.naturalOrder()
);
```

would return a stream that would produce this sequence:

```
1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3
```

Example 2:

```
merge(
    Stream.iterate(5, i->i-1),
    Stream.iterate(1, i->i+1),
    Comparator.naturalOrder()
);
```

would return an infinite (well, an `INT_MAX + 5` item) stream that would produce the sequence:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1 ...
```

As you can see, this is not merely `concat(first,second).sort()`, since (a) you can't sort infinite streams, and (b) even when you can sort the streams, it does not give the desired result.

Comment: You can't really merge them since, unless your question doesn't tell it all, none of the original streams are sorted; which means you cannot know in advance whether the element to read from stream 1 should effectively be fed before another element from that same stream, and you have the same problem with stream 2. Did you seriously expect a solution to exist apart from swallowing them both and sorting?

Comment: Apart from `Stream.concat(first, second).sorted(c);` I'm not sure you can do much...

Comment: I really don't understand what this is supposed to be doing.  @AJMansfield, can you give an input and output example of what you expect?  Depending on what you mean, this might not be that hopeless, but I can't tell.  What do you mean by "merging" the stream?  If it's, like, a mergesort merge from sorted import, it's doable.

Comment: @LouisWasserman It looks to me like he's comparing elements in pairs, i.e. the first two elements of the result are the first element of each stream (in one or the other order), the next two elements are the second element of each stream (one way or the other), etc...  Well, the first example follows that pattern.  The second one destroys my conjecture.  Never mind.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to implement a `Spliterator`, rather than going through `Stream.Builder`.  For this, you might even just go through an `Iterator`, since it's a fairly sequential operation.  Using Guava lightly,

```
return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(
    Iterators.mergeSorted(
      Arrays.asList(stream1.iterator(), stream2.iterator()),
      comparator),
    Spliterator.ORDERED),
  false /* not parallel */ );
```

Comment: I must be missing something but I don't see how this solves the OP's problem?

Comment: Given the updated explanation by the OP, this is in fact a correct answer.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Spliterator.ORDERED`?

Comment: Solution looks ok, though problem is very strange. You can also take source streams spliterators instead and if both of them has known size, you can sum it and create via `Spliterators.spliterator`. This way the resulting spliterator would split much better and operations like `toArray()` will work more effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Iterables.mergeSorted() from Guava

```
public static <T> Iterable<T> mergeSorted(Iterable<? extends Iterable<? extends T>> iterables,
                Comparator<? super T> comparator)
```

- https://javabot.evanchooly.com/javadoc/guava/22.0/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#mergeSorted-java.lang.Iterable-java.util.Comparator-